# Como alterar o tamanho da caixa de seleção (CheckBox) do ActiveX do Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-basic-6, activex

Não consigo alterar o tamanho da caixa de seleção activex do Excel, existe algum modo de alterar o tamanho, pois ela é muito pequena e a opção de tamanho da fonte fica desativada, queria muito deixa-la do tamanho desejado? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Quando você adiciona um elemento de activex, para poder redimensionar ou alterar qualquer propriedade do elemento certifique-se que o botão **Modo de Design** esta ativo, para poder editar seu controle. Este botão esta na guia **desenvolvedor** bem ao lado da opção de inserir os controles activeX.
Este é o botão que deve estar selecionado para possibilitar edição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Redimensionando arrstando com o mouse nas bordas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não da certo. Em propriedades do objeto ele só aumenta o tamanho da fonte da palavra "CheckBox" mas a caixinha continua do mesmo tamanho

Comment: Você consegue dimensionar o tamanho da box apenas arrastando as bordas da caixa com o mouse. Vou editar e postar a foto de como fiz aqui.

Comment: Sim, mas eu quero aumentar o tamanho do botão, o tamanho do objeto marcável

Comment: Ah sim entendi agora, então por padão você não consegue alterar o tamanha do iconi check, mais tem uma forma de simular o checknox com um tamanhão diferente. De uma olhada neste [link](https://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/alterar-tamanho/1423476/) e veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Eu já tentei esse código Vba, não deu certo. Deu certo ao baixar a planilha do usuário e o código funcionou. Mas quando eu utilizo um planilha em branco e adiciono o código eu não consigo selecionar o botão de um novo checkbox e nem aumentar seu tamanho, o tamanho só se aplica ao nome da caixa

Comment: Se vc quiser vc pode tentar fazer, é só pegar uma planilha em branco e adicionar uma nova caixa de seleção, até agora não sei como ele fez esse código aplicar no objeto

Comment: Eu fiz esse código é deu certo no sentido do checkbox, quando Clico na Label ele marca e desmarca a caixa. Criei uma planilha nova, adicionei uma Label, mudei o atributo backstyle para transparente, na propriedade text coloquei o ALT+0168, troquei a fonte para  Wingdings e deixei o tamanho 48, é no VBA adicionei o código mostrado no link e funcionou tranquilo, depois adicionei outra Label para apenas colocar o nome e posicionei ao lado. Aqui funcionou.

Comment: Você não conseguiu fazer o exemplo do link foi isso? Tenta fazer desse jeito que descrevi acima. Você tem adicionar uma Label não um checkbox.

Comment: Robson Silva, não consigo separar a caixa de seleção do nome "Checkbox", quando eu adiciono o código e mudo as propriedades da caixa, aparece uma segunda caixa de seleção no lugar do nome "checkbox" que fica ao lado da caixa padrão, essa caixa da para ajustar normalmente, porém a pequena caixinha ainda continua lá, como eu faço para separar o nome "checkbox" da caixa de marcação??